# OnClick Saving Only One ID at a time on UseState Array - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, use-state

i am trying to save favorite post ids in an array with button click. The thing is currently it is only saving one ID at a time in array and when you click you on another "click here" button , it removes the previous id and show you the current id. Currently my array is not saving previous saved Ids with the new one. I will appreciate it if someone explain why it is not working and is there something wrong in my code while saving the ids.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import Demopic from "../assets/img/demopic/4.jpg";
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { post } from 'jquery';

export default function Post(props) {
    
  const { id, title, body } = props.data;

  const [postid,setPostID] = useState([]);
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);  

  

  function onHandleOnClick(id) {

    setPostID([...postid, id]);
    
  };
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(postid);
  },[postid]);


  return (
    
            
    <div className="card">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-5 wrapthumbnail">
                <a href="post.html">
                    <div className="thumbnail dd" style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + Demopic + ')' }}>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-7">
                <div className="card-block">
                    <h2 className="card-title"><a href={'/post-detail/'+id} key={id}>{title}</a></h2>
                    
                    <h4 className="card-text">
                    {body.length > 100 ? `${body.substring(0, 90)}...` : body }
                    </h4>
                    <div className="metafooter">
                        <div className="wrapfooter text-left">
                            <span className="meta-footer-thumb">
                            <a href="author.html">
                                <img className="author-thumb" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e56154546cf4be74e393c62d1ae9f9d4?s=250&amp;d=mm&amp;r=x" alt="Sal"/></a>
                            </span>
                            <span className="author-meta">
                            <span className="post-name"><a href="author.html">Steve</a></span><br/>
                            <span className="post-date">22 July 2017</span><span className="dot"></span><span className="post-read">6 min read</span>
                            </span>
                            <button onClick={(e)=>onHandleOnClick(id)} value={id}>click here</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            
       
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your state is in each card. Each card will only have state of its own Id. To share state you need to store that elsewhere, perhaps a hook, state prop drilled from parent, global state etc

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita you mean i need to save it in its parent component ? Please explain.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your `Post` component is a single post, therefore each one of the `Post` components that you are creating will have their own `postId` array.

so if you have 10 posts you will have 10 different arrays, to test this, you can click on the same button multiple times and you will see that they array of that component will grow, for example the Id is 4 and you click multiple times you will see `[4 ,4, 4, 4.....]` and then if you do it on the Id 2 you will see `[2, 2, 2, 2....]`.

to fix this you should have on your parent component the array and then in then pass the update function to your childs, something like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
const [postid,setPostID] = useState([]);
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);  

  function onHandleOnClick(id) {
    setPostID([...postid, id]);
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(postid);
  },[postid]);


  return (<>
         <Post clickFavourite={onHandleOnClick}  ...other props/>
         <Post clickFavourite={onHandleOnClick}  ...other props/>
         <Post clickFavourite={onHandleOnClick}  ...other props/>
         <Post clickFavourite={onHandleOnClick}  ...other props/>
         <Post clickFavourite={onHandleOnClick}  ...other props/>
         </>)
}
```

and then in your child component (`Post`) you should remove the state and the handler and just use the parent function:

```
function Post(props) {
    
  const { id, title, body } = props.data;
  const { clickFavourite } = props;

  return (
    <button onClick={(e)=>clickFavourite(id)} value={id}>click here</button>
  )
}
```

notice that I deleted a lot of the content of the `Post` component just to read it easily.

also take into account that this can be done in different ways, this was the first way that came into my mind but you can use global states, states managers, hooks, etc etc. but as far as I see this is the easiest way and will get the job done

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping . Your approach is right but it is giving me this error now : PostCard.js:50 Uncaught TypeError: clickFavourite is not a function

Comment: @MA-2016 my mistake, I think you should look for `clickFavourite` inside `props` instead of `props.data`.

so finally it should be `const { clickFavourite } = props;`

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
const [postid,setPostID] = useState({});
```

Instead of

```
   const [postid,setPostID] = useState([]);
```

It will work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i am not interested in saving as object.I just want to save ids in one single array.