# How to store id from backend on button click using useState in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working in MERN project and i want to store `PM_id` on button click and store the `PM_id` in useState and later i want to fetch the `PM_id` from useState.

**I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72635589/onclick-saving-only-one-id-at-a-time-on-usestate-array-reactjs). but it didn't worked for me**

**My code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
const [storeid,setstoreid] = useState([])
 const getmemberidatte = (PM_id)=>{
        setstoreid(...storeid,[PM_id])
        console.log(storeid[0]?.PM_id);

    }

  return (
        <>
 <ol class="list-group list-group-numbered mt-4 ">

                                            {
                                                smember.map((item, i) => (

                                                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                                                        <div class="ms-2 me-auto">

                                                            <NavLink onClick={() => { getmemberid(item.PM_id) }} className="text-decoration-none"><div class="fw-bold">{item.member}</div></NavLink>


                                                        </div>
                                                        <button  onClick={()=>{ getmemberidatte(item.PM_id)}} className='btn btn-success me-3'>P</button>
                                                        <button className='btn btn-danger '>A</button>
                                                    </li>
                                                ))
                                            }
                                        </ol>
        </>
    )
}

export default Contractor
```

**In console i am getting `undefined`. The main part of code is  `<button  onClick={()=>{ getmemberidatte(item.PM_id);takeattendanceonbutton()}} className='btn btn-success me-3'>P</button>`**

**Please suggest me how do i get the id?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code. First off you are setting your state wrong the correct way to set an array state is:

```
setstoreid([...storeid, PM_id]);
```

Or more generally:

```
setstoreid((prev) => [...prev, PM_id]);
```

Also you are calling `console.log` right after your `setstoreid`, meaning that the state does not have time to update before you try to call it, therefore the value shown will always be one behind anyways. You can solve this by using a `useEffect` with `storeid` as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(storeid);
}, [storeid]);
```

This way `console.log` will only run after `storeid` has been updated. Now since all your function does is call `setstoreid` you can skip a step and remove the function meaning your button would be:

```
<button onClick={() => setstoreid([...storeid, item.PM_id])} className='btn btn-success me-3'>P</button>
```